# Bash registers backspace as space in from-scratch distribution

Tags: linux, bash

Heyo! Recently I've been in the process of creating a (not with LFS) from-scratch Linux Distro. Since I used Busybox, originally `ash` was the shell. But sadly, `ash` doesn't support a lot of what I never knew I needed so much - specifically, `!!`, brace expansion, and is finicky with parentheses. This leads me to want a `bash` shell.

Now, on the bash in my new system, whenever I press `backspace`, I receive a `space`. Imagine not being able to delete text! Furthermore, my up and down arrows don't work well -- if I go up, it'll show the last command -- and then if I try going down, it'll print out a space. And finally, `Ctrl+R` doesn't use a newline -- meaning if I press it, I get `-bash-5.0# (reverse-i-search)':` (all on one line).

I've tried setting my `TERM` variable and installing rxvt-unicode (it was a long shot, X isn't even installed).

I don't have these problems at all with `ash` and `dash`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these commands:

```
stty erase ^H
stty erase ^?
stty sane
```

They should help. But I do not know will it be a temporary solution. Then type

```
bash -l
```

Check. However the problem may be more complicated than I think. Hard to say. Maybe key mapping will be needed which is described here pretty well: [Linux console keybindings](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html)

Comment: I've tried all of the stty solutions before, and `bash -l` just opens a bash shell that still doesn't work. I'll be reading into keymaps, but I don't think that's the case (although one is probably not set yet, raw new system!)